# Missing main memory on Linux

Tags: linux, memory

On a new PC with 64 GB of main memory, I can only see about 60 GB, missing a whole 4 GB.

In BIOS all four modules of 16 GB each can be seen, and also that it adds up to the expected 64 GB.

But on Linux, I only see

```
$ free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       63726408     1917044    57576532      156680     4232832    60936548
Swap:      33554428           0    33554428
```

and

```
$ grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo 
MemTotal:       63726408 kB
```

which is around 60.77 GB of main memory.

---

Seeing this, I looked at my previous machine with 16 GB of main memory. Here too, one GB of the whole 16 GB is missing, leaving only 15.1 GB.

---

So, where and why are these 5-6% of main memory missing?

---

Addressing the possible duplicate [How do I read from /proc/$pid/mem under Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux)

My question is not about a single process memory, but all system memory, especially missing so much of it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read from /proc/$pid/mem under Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6301/how-do-i-read-from-proc-pid-mem-under-linux)

Comment: @PauloTomé No, the question there is about memory for a single process. I'm looking for the whole system memory and why there is missing such an awful lot of it.

Comment: 4gb graphics card?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34939514/graphics-card-memory-and-virtual-address-space-of-a-process

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/541424/5132 .

Comment: My 8GB system has about 1/4 a GB missing, as it is taken by the integrated graphics processor.

Comment: I updated the question, and it looks like graphics is the main offender. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least 2 or 3 GB seem to be occupied by the internal graphics adapater

```
Dez 23 12:27:06 pc04 kernel: [drm] amdgpu: 2048M of VRAM memory ready
Dez 23 12:27:06 pc04 kernel: [drm] amdgpu: 3072M of GTT memory ready.
Dez 23 12:27:06 pc04 kernel: [drm] GART: num cpu pages 262144, num gpu pages 262144
Dez 23 12:27:06 pc04 kernel: [drm] PCIE GART of 1024M enabled (table at 0x000000F400900000).
```

The previous system also used the internal graphics with similar results

```
Dez 17 19:56:23 pc01 kernel: [drm] radeon: 512M of VRAM memory ready
Dez 17 19:56:23 pc01 kernel: [drm] radeon: 1024M of GTT memory ready.
```

So it seems, graphics is where the main memory "vanishes".